# IIS 7.0 verbosity level

Tags: iis, iis-7

I can't seem to find an option to change the verbosity level of my IIS 7 log files (verbose, error, fatal etc). At the moment these things seem to be growing up exponentially and filling up a 700GB hard drive so I have to clean them up manually. If you go to a site's Logging dialog, there's no such option. Does IIS 7 log everything always?

F.

Comment: Are you talking about IIS Logs or your own application logs?

Comment: It's the logs per website that IIS generates.

Answer (score 1):

Which logging style do you use? W3C and Custom let you select which fields you want. Default actually leaves off a few key fields if you are doing any sort of analytics.

We actually disable the logs in lots of instances now that most folks do analytics in the cloud rather than on the disk. Very easy to turn back on if you need an audit trail.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the verbosity level on IIS7 only the fields that you want.